# How to upload file in dropzone.js with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

So I have a dropzone upload file parameter and I want to send that file to PHP so I can upload it to the database. I have a post parameter already for that file

```
$_POST['filetest']
```

And the form

```
<form id="recruit_form" action="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="text" id="name" class="form-input " name="name"
                           placeholder="<?php echo translate('name'); ?>" required>
                </div>

<input type="text" id="email" class="form-input " name="email"
                           placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>

 <div id="dropzone"></div>

</form>
```

So how do I get the file in PHP with the name of the post I assigned (filetest). Cause now, it doesn't have any name. The others work just fine, i tried adding name="filetest", but with no success, the only input that gives an error is this one.

Comment: https://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage "_If you want another name than file you can configure dropzone with the option paramName._"

Comment: I have no idea what you are even trying to ask here. The form you have shown does not contain any field named `filetest`. _“with the name of the post I assigned (filetest)”_ - I don’t see you assigning anything anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the input file field in the HTML form like `<input type="file" name="filetest" >`

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filetest"]["tmp_name"], 'Target file with path')) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["filetest"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
```

Hope this will help you.